# Ubuntu 20.04 blank screen after changing display scaling

Tags: display, 20.04

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS;
**Graphics**: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCle/SSE2;
**Monitor**: ASUS PB287Q;
**Port**: Display Port;

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and attempted to apply fractional scaling to the display.

When changing the display scale option to 150%, the screen went blank/black for roughly 10 seconds and then came back and showed an error, without the scaling applied.

With the fractional scale option still selected, I changed to 200%, and then the screen went blank and stayed that way.

After turning my PC off and on again, I can login normally, but after logging in, the screen turns blank again and I can't do anything.

I could just re-install the system, but I'm hoping for a solution in case I face this problem again in the future.

Comment: Same issue with the same graphics card. LG monitor however.

Comment: Same issue with nvidia 670 connected to an asus monitor using display port also. Not only my screen is black but my monitor says no signal.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a bit more to Wagner Michael's answer:

The following was performed successfully on Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Boot into Ubuntu Recovery mode.
2. Select "Drop into root user"
3. `sudo su - [Insert your username]`
4. `gsettings get org.gnome.mutter experimental-features`

   - Output should be = `"['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"`
5. `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "[]"`
6. reboot

Fixed.

Comment: Is this "Fixed" as in "Fractional Scaling Now Works" or "Broken Fraction Scaling Turned Off" ?

Answer (score 2):

Disabling fractional scaling via command line has done the job for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "[]"
```

Before experimental-features was set to `"['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"` in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Either you go into a different tty at boot (`Ctrl+Alt+F2`) or you do it from recovery mode and dropping into the root prompt. Either way, all you have to do is type:

`rm .config/monitors.xml`

To get rid of the fractional scaling config

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error (as I did ) when `gsettings set ...`

to the effect `cannot launch autolaunch d-bus without x-11 DISPLAY` use

```
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into Terminal at the login screen, remove the file `.config/dconf/user` and then `sudo reboot`. I think it resets the display settings to default.

This fixed my problem -- setting a fractional scaling and then black screen after login.

See [Black screen after logging in, after upgrading to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230945/black-screen-after-logging-in-after-upgrading-to-20-04)