# Black screen after logging in, after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: display, 20.04

I tried adding a new user and it works, I can login just fine with that user. So I tried removing (renamed it) my home directory, and that also fixes it.

Then I tried removing the `.config/monitors.xml` file, that didn't help. So now I have to try each file/directory in there one by one... but there are hundreds.

Any ideas on what specific files I should try moving/deleting to make my account work again?

Answer (score 7):

I thought it was gonna take hours but I found `.config/dconf/user` to be the culprit. Removing that file restored my ability to login without ending up in a black screen.

Comment: I cannot believe this solved my questions exactly...

Comment: Ivan's solution worked for me. But after deleting the user file, my mac theme was gone which does not really matter because I can just apply the theme again

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and found out that it was because of my radeon driver. According to [Can't Log In or Black Screen After Logging In with Ubuntu](https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/) I blacked list it and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was .config/dconf/user was read-only. I populated it in the kickstart, so yes, not ubuntu, but still gnome - don't hate. It is still relevant.

It was read-only in /etc/skel so got copied into the user's home as read-only.
Setting the /etc/skel/.config/dconf/user file to u+rw (or 600) solved the issue.

Symptom was the GUI would show after login for about a second, then go to a black screen. Pressing Ctrl-C multiple times caused the system to return to the Login screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to log in to the recovery mode properly, so the problem was definitely in the Nvidia drivers used in the normal mode as the recovery mode uses the Nouveau drivers.

So, upon restart, drop into the root shell prompt (either via the GRUB menu or CTRL+ALT+Fn) (Fn can be F1 to F6) and run:

```bash
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The above command will autoinstall the drivers suited to your machine and update them.
Then, verify it using:

```bash
nvidia-smi
```

And, run:

```bash
sudo reboot
```

Now, you'll be able to log back in properly to your desktop with updated drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Andromeda above, I followed the same link above [Black Screen Or Login Issues Ubuntu 22.04](https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/).

Couldn't Blacklist Radeon graphics card. My permission were denied for some reason.

Anyways, followed making another test user to check if test user is working fine. Then moved the old configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Black screen or mouse/touchpad freeze problem after login is resolved with the following actions:

1. Mask the NetworkManager-wait-online service =>
   https://askubuntu.com/a/1166492/1761962
2. Edit the system.conf file at /etc/systemd folder => https://askubuntu.com/a/1160776/1761962
3. Display hidden Startup Apps, then uncheck unnecessary startup apps => https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShowHiddenStartupApplications
4. Reconfigure gdm3 => https://askubuntu.com/a/1260286

---

It needs additional commands for the unnecessary startup apps like below.

```
systemctl mask org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.service --user
systemctl mask org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service --user
systemctl mask org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wwan --user
systemctl mask org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.UsbProtection --user
```

Answer (score 0):

tldr
If you're using a virtual machine with a 4k monitor, try logging in on a 1080 monitor or try dropping your display settings down to 1080.

---

Didn't begin after upgrading, but suddenly I also got a black screen after logging in.

Moving virtualbox to my other monitor before logging in fixes the issue.
I haven't narrowed it down to determine if it's an issue with virtualbox, or ubuntu. Either way, I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that I changed Monitor 1 to use 4k--Monitor II is still 1080.