# Changing cursor size to max breaks my system

Tags: display, 20.04, cursor

After I change the cursor size to the max size, available in cursor size under Universal Access (Also shown in this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLsKG.png)) my system just crashes. Even after I restart the most that happens is a blank/black screen stays active after I login.
I tried changing the cursor size to every available option and only when I change it to the max size the black screen thingy happens.

Thanks to Ivan's question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230945/black-screen-after-logging-in-after-upgrading-to-20-04/1236387#1236387) I was able to solve my issue.

And yes this didn't just happen once or twice it happens every time I change the cursor size to max. The solution that Ivan posted isn't that much of a fuss to go through, delete one file and everything is good but the only problem is that my desktop resets to what it is/was when you fresh install Ubuntu.

If anyone could help me with what's causing this to happen I would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to accept the answer?

Answer (score 3):

After login as another user, you have to follow these steps with root password to reset the cursor size.

Let the two user's name be userA and userB. You want to reset cursor size for userA.

1. Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) with userB.
2. Enter these commands in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo su - userA [provide root password]
   dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 24
   ```

and you are done.

Comment: You are life saver!! Thanks

Comment: Same same. Thanks. I tried to file this as a bug and found Ubuntu's process to be lengthy. I have no idea which program to profile to get information about this, nor how to profile it at login.